# Weird box-shadow artifacts in webkit

Tags: html, css

Anyone have any idea what could be causing the blue box to the right of the input field?

It's been the bane of my existence the past few days. Only appears intermittently. The markup for each input is like so:

```
<div class="input text">
    <label for="pass">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" class="required"  tabindex="30"/>
</div>
```

Things to note are that the label is positioned on top of the field and then dimmed/faded out when clicked/typed on.

This only happens on webkit on Mac and apparently Vista.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BQcv.jpg

EDIT: Sorry, the CSS:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"] { 
            height: 30px;
            outline: none;
            -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow 0.3s linear;
            -moz-transition: -moz-box-shadow 0.3s linear;
            transition: box-shadow 0.3s linear;
        }

        .input.text input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="text"]:active, .input.text input[type="password"]:focus, input[type="password"]:active {
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 12px #82cce8;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 12px #82cce8; /* chrome seems to show a smaller box shadow */
            box-shadow: 0 0 12px #82cce8;
        }

        .input.text input, .input.text span.field {
            padding: 10px 15px;
            width: 92%;
            font-size: 2em;
            font-family: 'HelveticaNeueW01-45Ligh', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            border: 1px solid #cecece;
            -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
            -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: -2px -2px 3px rgba(205,205,205, 0.3);
            -moz-box-shadow: -2px -2px 3px rgba(205,205,205, 0.3);
            box-shadow: -2px -2px 3px rgba(205,205,205, 0.3);
        }
            input::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #e2e2e2;}
            input:-moz-placeholder { color: #e2e2e2;}
```

The containing div just has a padding of 20px.

Also, sorry sdleihssirc, had to re-link image due to edit.

Comment: We'll probably need to see the CSS.

Comment: ..and sandwiches! ( I see nothing weird in here http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/9Swks/ )

Comment: haha, a solid answer would get my best efforts for sandwich procurement

Comment: i can't reproduce the artifact.. i'm using latest chrome on win7

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem to show up in Win7. Only Chrome/safari on OSX and, I've been told, vista.

Comment: I checked that out in OSX with Safari 5.0.5 and Chrome 14 and just not seeing it at least with the code you provided. Are you sure its not some other css or html in the page that is messing with it?

Comment: Yeah, I tried a test page with just the input with its wrapper, showed up. Will post a link to the page shortly

Comment: I still not see no artifacts, with your test page too (win7, latest chrome)

Comment: Yes, like I mentioned, it only shows up on macs and vista. I'm running snow leopard on virtualbox and it shows up intermittently. Looks like a rendering glitch.

Comment: @Jerry I'm still not seeing it in my mac. :/ ( and I checked your updated url.. just to be clear. )

Comment: *pulls hair out* Okay, will try out a few markup changes... Btw, are you on 10.6.2?

Comment: @Chris nope. Figured it was some rendering bug and took a different approach to field highlighting.

Answer (score 3):

I can't duplicate this on Safari 5.1 (10.7), and I know you've found an alternate tactic, but try [-webkit-background-clip](http://tumble.sneak.co.nz/post/928998513/fixing-the-background-bleed) out and let me know if it is related.

```
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
```

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

Fix by [Matteo Spinelli](http://cubiq.org/webkit-weird-box-shadow-bug-with-fix):

```
position: relative / absolute
top: 0
```

Here's another example:
(from Safari 6.0.2; background should fill the button but it does so below the text only)
http://cl.ly/image/1c1g030n2V0d
http://cl.ly/image/0y3E3u1t391w